# SSH typing delay

Tags: command-line, ssh

Whenever I use ssh, there is a typing delay of about 2 seconds which is very annoying. Is there any way I can fix it? I'm on Kubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I've seen that on bad connections. Does it happen on every machine you connect to?

Comment: Actually, is there a way I can test it? I only used SSH to connect to https://overthewire.org

Comment: I just connected to the `maze` game and the typing response speed was fine for me.

Comment: I too connected to the maze game, the there still was some typing delay. And I don't think I have low speed internet connection, its 4.4 Mbps according to https://fast.com/

Comment: Mine is 200 Mbps but not sure if that's it.